# I got an error named there is no attribute "BoxShadow". I have a code as follows:

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart

179:22: Error: No named parameter with the name '#2'.
BoxShadow(
^^...
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/box_shadow.dart:35:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const BoxShadow({
^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: put your code...

Comment: I got that solved, Thank you

It was for another Function